# configure phpmyadmin configuration storage

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin

I have a setup a user 'pma'@'localhost' with a password and SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE privileges.
I have a database phpmyadmin with the tables built from create_tables.sql
I have edited config.inc.php . . .

```
/* User used to manipulate with storage */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'XXXXXXXX';

/* Storage database and tables */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
```

One thing I've never found documented is which tables to place the configuration options in and in what format.
I have the following inserted into a single row in the pma_userconfig table

```
username    | ''
timevalue   | 2013-08-30 12:23:45
config_data |$cfg['NumRecentTables']=0;
             $cfg['NavigationTreeDisplayDbFilterMinimum']=999;
             $cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping']=FALSE;
             $cfg['MaxRows']=100;
             $cfg['MaxTableList'] = 100;
             $cfg['MaxDBList'] = 100;
```

all other tables are empty except pma_history which has populated itself.

NONE of those configuration options is having any effect. I've tried different usernames in the table record. I've tried a record for each option.

Can anyone tell me what's missing here? Is this the right table, the right format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to edit directly these tables: they are populated by phpMyAdmin. For example, when you create a query bookmark via the interface, when you change a setting via the Settings tab, etc.

Comment: Yes, that finally happened.  I don't know what I did, because I've been trying so many options, but finally after setting the prefs for the hundredth time in phpmyadmin they were written to the userconfig table.  I guess something in my configuration was not correct initially.  Thanks.